# Show that $h(A)=\int_A f \, d\mu$ is a measure.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a simple function on a measure space ($\Omega,\Sigma,\mu$). Let $h:\Sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function with $h(A)=\int_A f \, d\mu$. Show that ($\Omega,\Sigma,h$) is a measure space.

So I need to show that $h$ is a measure:

- $h(\emptyset)= \int_\emptyset f\,d\mu=0$ (Ok.)
- Let $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be pairwise disjoint sets in $\Sigma$.
  I need to show that $h(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}h(A_n)$.

Can I just say: $h\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n\right)=\int_{\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}} f \, d\mu=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\int_{A_n}f \, d\mu=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}h(A_n)$? Is the second "$=$" correct or do I have to use the definition of simple functions?

Comment: I think you have to assume that $f$ is non-negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second equality is correct but I think you are supposed to use the fact that $f$ is a simple function. Then you just have to show that for a disjoint union

$$\mu \left(\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}U_{k}\right)\cap A\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mu(U_k \cap A)$$

where $A$ is a measurable set.

Answer (score 1):

$$
h\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n\right)=\int\limits_{\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n} f \, d\mu = \int\limits_\Omega f\cdot 1_{\bigcup\limits_n A_n}   \,d\mu \tag 1
$$
where for every measurable set $B$,
$$
1_B (x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }x\in B, \\ 0 & \text{if }x\not\in B.  \end{cases}
$$
Now observe that
$$
1_{\bigcup\limits_n A_n} = \sum_n 1_{A_n},
$$
so $(1)$ becomes
$$
\int\limits_\Omega \sum_n f\cdot1_{A_n} \, d\mu.
$$
If you can use the fact that $f$ is a simple function to show that this is equal to
$$
\sum_n \int\limits_\Omega f\cdot 1_{A_n} \,d\mu = \sum_n \int\limits_{A_n} f\,d\mu = \sum_n h(A_n),
$$
then you've got it.

Comment: Why `\int\limits` instead of `\int` in display mode?

Comment: The expression $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n$ is a bit unusual for a subscript in such an expression and it seemed awkward without \limits. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Did I mention the position of the index of *unions*? I believe not.